# SQLite3 data 'corruption'

Tags: sqlite, 64-bit

I'm developing a Delphi XE3 app. on Windows 7 **64 bit**. 
It writes to an SQLite3 database and reads back the data.

If I read the data using the dos cmdline, it's fine.

However, the data returned via the dbExpress control in Delpih OR using SQLiteExpert is garbage. I have a suspicion that it's down to using 64bit Windows, but am totally stumped.

[SQLiteExpert screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/94039122@N05/8558339892/)

Any ideas folks?

Commandline sqlite3 shows sensible data:

```
sqlite> select distinct * from flight;
1|38926|Wed, 13 Mar 2013 15:54:19 GMT|EE35|38927|EGBB|EGPD|ofp|100720
2|38926|Wed, 13 Mar 2013 15:54:19 GMT|EE35|38927|EGBB|EGPD|ofp|100720
```

Delphi code (also tried TSQLQuery with same problems):

```
qrySelect := TSQLDataSet.Create(nil);
qrySelect.CommandType := ctQuery;
qrySelect.SQLConnection := conn;
qrySelect.CommandText := 'select distinct flight_brief_id, brief_id, brief_date from flight';

qrySelect.Open;
try
showmessage(inttostr(qryselect.Fields.Count)); // returns 3 as expected
qrySelect.First;
while not qrySelect.Eof do
begin
    strA := qryselect.Fields[0].AsString; 
    strB := qryselect.Fields[1].AsString;
    strC := qryselect.Fields[2].AsString;
    qrySelect.Next;
end;
finally
  qrySelect.Close;
end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a wrong encoding. How are you writing the data?

Comment: Via Delphi dbExpress component or via the commandline sqlite3.exe

Comment: Please show the code, and an example record.

Comment: Initial post edited to add code

Comment: And what are the contents of `strA`/`B`/`C`?

Comment: *What* garbage? What is the result of calling `BinToHex` on such a string?

Comment: It seems to have gone into null mode now, instead of garbage mode! However, I'm not sure exactly how to call bintohex. I've tried one method (not easy to post here as I can't do lf without posting ), but the effect can be seen on http://www.flickr.com/photos/94039122@N05/8558339892/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not answered as such, but I have a workaround and a better idea of where the problem lies in case anyone has some ideas for me!

I dusted down a win XP box and found exactly the same problem, so it's not a 64 bit issue. Nice!

So, I removed the params from the insert TSQLQuery

```
example of usage : qryInsert.Params.CreateParam(ftString, 'BriefID', ptInput);
```

and replaced by

```
qryInsert.SQL.Text := 'insert into flight (brief_id, brief_date, flightno, '+
                    ' flight_brief_id, pod, poa, ofp, flight_date) '+
                    ' values ( '''+
                      brief_id+''', '''+
                      brief_date+''', '''+
                      flightno+''', '''+
                      flight_brief_id+''', '''+
                      pod+''', '''+
                      poa+''', ''ofp'', '''+
                      flight_date+''' )';
```

Not pretty but it worked. And on the 64 bit system. So it's something to do with the params, but not a clue what!!